# Using Parse with Angular2 (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, parse-platform, tsd

(Yes, I know angular2 is beta, but I'm just trying it out)

I've followed the angular2 quickstart here: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

And that's working fine. Now I want to try to use it with Parse, so I found out tsd was probably the way to go to access Parse from TypeScript.

I went on and did:

```
tsd init
tsd install parse --save
```

It added Parse (parse.d.ts) + its dependencies (node.d.ts, jquery.d.ts and underscore.d.ts.

Now, the node.d.ts part was abit problematic since angular2 already had this added, so each definition was duplicated, I tried to solve this by:

```
Remove "typings/node" folder (node/node.d.ts)
Remove '/// <reference path="node/noded.ts" />' from typings/tsd.d.ts
Remove '/// <reference path="node/noded.ts" />' from typings/parse/parse.d.ts
```

I figured, this will work since node.d.ts is available already, right?

Well, it's not working and I have no clue why. I get an error `node_modules/angular2/typings/angular-protractor/angular-protractor.d.ts(1679,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'JQueryStatic', but here has type 'cssSelectorHelper'.` But this is not the main problem, because it looks like proceeds after that.

This is what makes `npm start` "crash":

```
[1] events.js:141
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: watch node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/examples/core/ts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js ENOSPC
[1]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
[1]     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)
[1]     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)
[1]     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/david/repo/angular2-toodeloo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
[1]     at setFsWatchListener (/home/david/repo/angular2-toodeloo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/david/repo/angular2-toodeloo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/david/repo/angular2-toodeloo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/david/repo/angular2-toodeloo/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
[1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Full output can be found here: http://pastebin.com/xE3u3qUh

*UPDATE*

I relized the error above was in the angular2 examples, so I removed the examples and got rid of the error. But when I did "npm install parse", the error was back, but in another place.. This time: `Error: watch node_modules/opt-merger/node_modules/lodash/lang/isFunction.js ENOSPC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I got this was that there was to many watches (inotify) in the filsystem. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B for how to increment the maximun number of watches!

Comment: I am stuck with Parse in Angular2. Can you please share your basic code. I am getting errors while trying to import 'parse' module.